# Hide country at checkout when not a Wholesale Customer?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am looking to add a php code in functions for the following question? (woocommerce)
I want to hide a few countries (Germany, Denmark) at the checkout page when you are **not** logged in as a wholesale customer?

Comment: We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using woocommerce_countries filter you can do it like this

```
function wholesale_country_restrictions( $country) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Change administrator with your user role
    if( !is_user_logged_in() || isset( $user->roles[0] ) && $user->roles[0] != 'wholesale_customer') {
        unset($country["DE"]);
        unset($country["DK"]);
    } 
    return $country;
    
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'wholesale_country_restrictions', 10, 1 );
```

Add the code in your functions.php file in your active parent/child theme

Comment: Coding appears to not be working as my site gives "A critical error has occurred on this"

Comment: The code is tested and works w/o problems. Could you share what is the error ?

Comment: When I paste the code in my functions.php file, save it and then refresh my webpage the whole page goes down and gives the error: "A critical error has occurred on this" (In Dutch)

Comment: How to debug error - https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ . After that share error you get in your log

Comment: I got an automated error message via email saying:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Collator::asort() must be of the type array, null given in /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php:1807
Stack trace:
#0 /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(1807): Collator->asort(NULL, 1)
#1 /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-countries.php(53): wc_asort_by_locale(NULL)

Comment: #2 /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-countries.php(38): WC_Countries->get_countries()
#3 /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-countries.php(250): WC_Countries->__get('countries')
#4 /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(1307): WC_Countries->get_allowed_countries()
#5 /home/deb97341/domains/babybello.nl/public_h

Comment: I have updated my function. The problem was that we are not returning anything if user role is not the one we check.

Comment: The code now doesn't give an error, but when i visit the checkout page (without login as wholesale_customer) still seeing the countries?

Comment: Ah sorry i though you want only for wholesale customers to hide. So change $user->roles[0] == 'administrator' with $user->roles[0] != 'administrator' . I have updated the answer

Comment: No wait, you are not following.
I ONLY want to hide countries when you are NOT logged in as a wholesale_customer

Comment: Super works. Now I only need a bit of coding to make sure in the country dropdown the empty spaces (where the hided countries are) are removed?

Comment: Hi, do you maybe have a bit of coding to make sure in the country dropdown the empty spaces (where the hided countries are) are removed?